# Propagation of UITouch events

Tags: swift, uitouch

I have views arranged as shown in attached figure.

[image]

1. MAINVIEW is an added subview to UISCROLLVIEW

   ```
   class NotewallController:UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

       var bgImage:UIImageView?
       var bgScrollView:UIScrollView?
       var masterView:UIView?

       override func viewDidLoad() {

           self.bgScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
           self.bgScrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
           self.bgScrollView!.delegate = self
           self.bgScrollView!.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
           self.bgScrollView!.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
           self.view.addSubview(self.bgScrollView!)

           masterView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,1000,1000))
           masterView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
           masterView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
           bgScrollView!.addSubview(masterView!)

           let note = WALLVIEW(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 30, 30))
           self.masterView!.addSubview(note)

       }
   ```
2. WALLVIEW is a subclass of UIVIEW

   class WallView:UIView {

   ```
   override init(frame: CGRect) {

      super.init(frame: frame)

       let bgImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
       bgImageView.image = UIImage(named: "stickynote.png")
       bgImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
       self.addSubview(bgImageView)

       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "WallNoteTapped:")
       bgImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

   }
   ```

My issue is in WALLVIEW. As you can notice, I have a TAP GESTURE in WALLVIEW. When the program is executed, a tap of WALLVIEW object doesn't call the "WallNoteTapped:" method. Suspecting the touch events are not passed to WALLVIEW object "note".

I am not able to understand why "WallNoteTapped:" method is not triggered.

Thanks

EDIT:
I made WALLVIEW subclass of UIImageView rather than UIView and it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an UITapGestureRecognizer cancel te touches in its subviews.

Try to set cancelsTouchesInView to false.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it didn't solved my issue.What solved my issue is, I made WALLVIEW subclass of UIImageView rather than UIView and it worked.

Comment: Then the problem was that UIImageView as default has userInteractionEnabled to false.